# Electric potential and electric field within a hollow sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

suppose there is a hollow conducting sphere with a charge inside it, but not in the center of the sphere. then there is a point charge like $q'$ outside this sphere. here is my question:
 does the $q'$ outside of the sphere change the electric potential and the electric field of the center of the sphere?
<br. My idea is that due to the uniqueness existing in this question, the electric field won't change; but I don't really know about the potential.

Comment: Can you clearly describe the question the way it's written makes it harder to understand you may consider adding a diagram.

Comment: dielectric? conducting? superconducting?

Comment: @JEB sorry for the lack of info, it's a conducting sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, consider the hollow conducting spherical shell without the charge in the interior to see what the effects of the exterior charge are. For the external charge, its field lines terminate perpendicularly on the spherical surface and it induces a charge distribution on the conducting surface in such a way as to bring the entire surface to a constant potential. If this were not so there would be currents flowing in the surface, which is not the case for an external static charge. Now since any closed surface inside the sphere encloses no charge, the electric field at any interior point of the region bounded by the conductor is zero. A vanishing electric field corresponds to a constant potential which may be chosen at any arbitrary value. One is then at liberty to choose this constant as zero so that any field effects inside the region bounded by the conductor is due only to a charge introduced into the region.

Comment: why can the constant potential be chosen at any arbitrary value? don't we have to use ,for example Helmholtz theorem to find the potential?

Comment: The potential at any point where there is no charge density satisfies Laplace's equation, ${\nabla}^2\phi=\nabla \cdot \vec E=0$. If the Electric field is zero, i.e. $\vec E=0$, then the only potential $\phi$, which satisfies Laplace's equation is $\phi=constant$.

Comment: This all translates into the fact that only the internal charge gives any contribution to the field inside the region bounded by the conductor.

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot